# Track Events using Facebook SDK on Nativescript App using nativescript-facebook plugin

Tags: facebook, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I am trying to connect the an app built with Nativescript-Vue with Facebook to set up ads and track the performance. I am reading through the documentation of https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-facebook but have not found how should I implement the tracking features (specifically Track App Installs and App Opens). Does the plugin work for events? Thanks.-

I also see that the official facebook Quick Start for iOS SDK tutorial, includes some xml for iOS that it is not included in the plugin docs:

```
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>XXXXXXX</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>XXXXX</string>
```

Any idea why?

Thanks!

Comment: As that plgun is wrapper for facebooksdk, you should be able to track events. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/getting-started-app-events-ios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin do not implement events yet. But you may do it by accessing the native apis on the [iOS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/getting-started-app-events-ios) / [Android](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/getting-started-app-events-android) SDK.

Learn more about accessing native apis for [iOS](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/ios-runtime/Marshalling-Overview) / [Android](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/android-runtime/marshalling/java-to-js) from JavaScript in the docs.

Comment: Thanks. I hope analytics will be added soon to the plugin.